# What does the Indigo Tribe oath mean?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

The [oath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigo_Tribe#Oath) of the Indigo Tribe is:

> Tor lorek san, bor nakka mur,
>   Natromo faan tornek wot ur.
>   Ter Lantern ker lo Abin Sur,
>   Taan lek lek nok--Formorrow Sur!

Has it ever been translated?  If so, what does it mean in English?

Comment: I found [this translation](https://whatculture.com/comics/origins-of-10-different-lantern-corps-and-their-oaths?page=7): "In sorrowful day, in misfortune of night, we help those who need our might. With the lantern power of Abin Sur, we rid your miseries with compassion and might", but I'm uncertain of it's accuracy.

Answer (score 10):

I took the oath through Google translate today, cycling through all the languages and writing down likely substitutes for words.  A few were troublesome and I treated them as contractions, which smoothed things out.  (Only a little, though.)  This is what I came up with:

> Dream-gate shade, and living wall,
>   Natromo returns to watch the gap from within.
>   Having Lantern-vessels of Abin Sur,
>   Enough playing games - from right now on!

1. I know it has no color reference.  This is as good a literal
   translation using Earth languages as I could wrench it into saying.
2. It doesn't even touch the language used in the comics.
3. I know little to nothing about the story line.  I was interested
   because it was a linguistic challenge to me. (And the Green Lantern
   is a cool dude.)
4. I will not cite it, as it took a good 3 hours to run all the
   searches and checks.  Running it through Google Translate will give
   you an idea on how I started, just cycle the languages.

Here is the literal translation that I used, line by line:

> Tor lorek san, bor nakka mur,
>   Gate shade dream, live and wall
>
> Natromo faan tornek wot ur.
>   Natromo return (to see the gap(gate)) from within
>
> Ter Lantern ker lo Abin Sur,
>   Having Lantern vessels (of) Abin Sur
>
> Taan lek lek nok--Formorrow Sur!
>   To game play enough - (fore tomorrow) on

Answer (score 8):

#### There is no translation of the Indigo Tribe's oath. It has been speculated it is not necessarily the Oath that matters but the cadence which activates the power.

The Wikipedia Entry on the [Indigo Tribe's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigo_Tribe) adds some commentary from the writer Geoff Johns:

> As with the other Corps of the emotional spectrum, the Indigo Tribe charges its rings by reciting an oath, but uses a power staff instead of a power battery. In its first extended appearance, the Indigo Tribe speaks a language that the power ring cannot translate, although Indigo-1 later explains that her Tribe can speak languages others can understand. Regardless, the oath has only been rendered in the aforementioned fictional language. Johns (the series' writer) has said that the Corps oaths have a tempo regardless of what language they are spoken in, adding: "But speaking of languages, the Indigo Tribe speaks an interesting one."
>
> “Tor lorek san, bor nakka mur,
>
> Natromo faan tornek wot ur.
>
> Ter Lantern ker lo Abin Sur,
>
> Taan lek lek nok--Formorrow Sur!”
>
> —Indigo-1, Blackest Night #5 (January 2010)

Answer (score 2):

It's evidently unknown, and there isn't a translator yet for the language. Did find one [forum post](http://thegreenlanterncorps.com/Forum/showthread.php?t=14446) that has some translations of the language, but nothing definitive.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the comic books for direct translations, I got this:

> Tor lorek san, bor nakka mur,
>
> Natromo faan tornek wot ur.
>
> Ter Lantern ker lo Abin Sur,
>
> Taan lek lek nok--Formorrow Sur!

Translated:

[Tor] [lorek] **following**, [bor] **blackest night**.
**Natromo** [fann] [tornek] [wot] [ur].
**His Lantern our guide Abin Sur.**
[Taan] **multiple lights may compassion guide you--Indigo Power!**

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F! Can you add your sources from where you got this quote and the translation?

Answer (score 1):

I know the word "nok" means "may compassion be with you". It's kin of their catchphrase.

Answer (score 0):

In sorrowful day, in misfortunate night,
We help those, who need our might,
With the Lanturn power of Abin Sur,
We rid your misery....with compassionate might!

Comment: Do you have a source for this?  I like how it goes, but I don't think this is official.

Comment: This is supported by [this site](https://whatculture.com/comics/origins-of-10-different-lantern-corps-and-their-oaths?page=7), but having an actual comic book reference would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help?

The Book of the Black:
The Burned-In Thoughts of William Hand

### Chapter 1, Verse 7

NEK-SAN "NOK?"

NEKRON LOR LEK NEK NEK SURA
GUARDIANS WA RET SCOPET. KLEK KLEK
NEE. LOK NAK LORA LORUUTA GORGER RO
RO. LOKOK NLETT ABIN SUR RATCH HAL
JORDAN ET SINESTRO DORO GREEN
LANTERNS. SUR MUNK HARK TE KEKAKEK
OA LEDD MONROTT DORO SCOPET.
NOK. SCOPET LOR, "LET THERE
BE LIGHT!" KLEK OCTA ROQ?

LEKORA LEK LEK!

RET ROGORA LARFLEEZE ET ATROCITUS
DORO SAINT WALKER ET STAR SAPPHIRE
KER QUR. KLOK SINESTRO DEF HART TE
PARALLAX ET HECTOR HAMMOND.
TUR HECTOR HAMMOND LOR LEK
SUR SHARK. ET DORO RADSAW
LETT RESMUN AQUAWARR.

TOR LORKE SAN, BOR NAKKA MUR.
NATROMO FANN TORNEK WOT UR.
TER LANTERN KER LO ABIN SUR.
TANN LEK LEK NOK -- FORMORROW SUR!

NOK. - "MAY COMPASSION GUIDE YOU."

LER ORAK TE WILLIAM HAND. -
"MY NAME IS WILLIAM HAND."

LUCA. - "PLEASE."

KLOK NER! - "HELP ME!"

Comment: Well this isn't very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, after looking at what the direct translation has (which to me is a bit rough and literal) I feel it would in an English style cadence would go like this..

Following empty day, the blackest night.
Natromo keeps the indigo's sight,
Guided by Abin Sur's guiding right,
May compassion lead you, with every light.

Using the translated words as a rough guide and in the way a normal person would speak an oath it seems as though it would go like this.

following the empty use of emotion, it caused the blackest night. while they fought natromo... their guardian, protected the battery and their focus. they set their values based on what abin sur said was truth. "nok" is compassion with you, so a similar saying would be may it lead you instead of with you. in this case with the compassion's ability to emulate every light.

Comment: D'you have sources?

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE!  This site values facts over opinions.  If you have (official) sources for your translation, please state them.